# Search and replace with case preservation and plurals

Tags: search, replace, case-folding

Is there a way (or package) to search and replace code like:

```
class Account
  def list_accounts
  end
end
```

to

```
class Company
  def list_companies
  end
end
```

Basically I want to replace account(s) with compan(y/ies)

Vim does this with [Subvert](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/smart-search-with-subvert/)

Comment: The "case" part of your question should be the default behaviour of `query-replace`. That is, if you ask to replace "account" with "company", then "Account" will be replaced with "Company". Is that not what happens for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Retaining the cases on replacing

By default, emacs retains the cases when replacing.

From the [emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Replacement-and-Case.html#Replacement-and-Case),

> When the newstring argument is all or partly lower case, replacement commands try to preserve the case pattern of each occurrence. Thus, the command
>
> ```
> M-x replace-string <RET> foo <RET> bar <RET>
> ```
>
> replaces a lower case `foo` with a lower case `bar`, an all-caps `FOO` with `BAR`, and a capitalized `Foo` with `Bar`. (These three alternatives—lower case, all caps, and capitalized, are the only ones that replace-string can distinguish.)

Ensure that the `case-replace` variable is `t` (which it is, by default).

## Replacing with plurals

You can try `query-replace-regexp` (`C-M-%`) then replace

```
account\(s\)?
```

with

```
compan\,(if (string= \1 "s") "ies" "y)
```

Comment: I wonder if this could be combined with http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/plural.el to come up with `replace-string-with-plural` or equivalent.

Comment: `"y` should be `"y"`